# how to fix 'size', 'occurred at index City' error

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to do the example in Use Python & Pandas to replace NaN in the 'size' column with a specific value, depending on the City. In the example below i am trying to assign a value of 18 if the City is St. Louis.

I have used the lambda function to do it since the original dataframe has lot of rows with the repeat of City names and only few of them have NaN values.
when i run the code I am getting an error - KeyError: ('size', 'occurred at index City')

below is the snippet of the code -

```
raw_data = {'City' : ['Dallas', 'Chicago', 'St Louis', 'SFO', 'St Louis'],
            'size': [24, 36, 'NaN', 'NaN', 22],
            'Type' : ['Pie', 'Hallo', 'Zombi', 'Dru', 'Zoro']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df

df['size'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['size'].fillna(value = 18 if x['City' == 'St Louis'] else x['size'], axis = 1, inplace = True))
df
```

Expected - 18 to be populated in size column for St. Louis
Actual - KeyError: ('size', 'occurred at index City')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution by *fillna* method

```
df['size'] = df['size'].fillna(18)
```

**EDITED**

What I failed to notice - that you populate cells with *NaN* string, not with real *NaN* values.

If you change your input data as

```
raw_data = {'City' : ['Dallas', 'Chicago', 'St Louis', 'SFO', 'St Louis'],
            'size': [24, 36, np.NaN, np.NaN, 22],
            'Type' : ['Pie', 'Hallo', 'Zombi', 'Dru', 'Zoro']
}
```

Then the following method will allow you to re-populate *size* columns cells by city names

```
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df[['City', 'size']] = df.set_index('City')['size'].fillna({'St Louis': 18, 'SFO': 20}).reset_index()
```

Comment: it would not help my case, since the other City (SFO) which also has a NaN value needs to be populated by different size.

Comment: Actually, since you set values to string _NaN_, not to _np.NaN_, _fillna_ would not work

Comment: PS Setting values to *NaN* string is sort of counter-productive, use *None* - and pandas will convert it to *NaN* value

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is set the size of St. Louis, you can run:

```
df.loc[df['City'] == 'St Louis', 'size'] = 18
```

However, if you instead want to set all values of `NaN` to `18`, you could likewise run:

```
df.loc[df['size'] == 'NaN', 'size'] = 18
```

And if you'd just like to set the size of all St. Louis entries where the size is `NaN`, you could do:

```
df.loc[df['City'] == 'St Louis' and df['size'] == 'NaN', 'size'] = 18
```

Comment: only the NaN values of the City is to be replaced by 18. If the City already has a size, i want to keep it.

Comment: I have edited the dataframe which would make more sense now.